# classic thesis lyx language problem

Tags: lyx, languages, classicthesis, changes

What changes (in the tex-configure file i guess) should i make to use this package in greek language? when i export it to pdflatex the text is gibberish. i think this is the relevant part

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{latin9}{inputenc} % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"
 \usepackage{inputenc}

\PassOptionsToPackage{greek,american}{babel}   % change this to your language(s)
% Spanish languages need extra options in order to work with this template
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
 \usepackage{babel}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only need Greek, do

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
```

If your TeX distribution is up-to-date this will be sufficient, provided you save your documents as UTF-8.

With an older TeX distribution (such as TeX Live 2012), one has to add

```
\usepackage[LGRx]{fontenc}
```

With much older TeX distributions something like

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
```

could work. But the best is to upgrade to the last release of the TeX system.

---

Note: the syntax proposed by `classicthesis` is surely not what I'd use; the suggested code should be the clearer

```
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a complete upgrade, it is also sufficient to install/update the packages `greek-fontenc` and `greek-inputenc` from CTAN.

Never ever use "LGRx" as *last* option to `fontenc`. This is a "pseudo font encoding" which provides "LGR" with better definitions. Instead, you can write

```
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
```

if the default font encoding should be Latin and

```
\usepackage[LGRx,T1, LGR]{fontenc}
```

if the default font encoding should be Greek.

However, I recommend `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}` in connection with

```
 \usepackage{textalpha}.
```

This avoids the "pseudo name" hack and is upwards compatible with the new `babel-greek` and `greek-fontenc` packages.
(The `textalpha` package ensures that the comprehensive LGR definitions are
loaded and makes the `\textalpha ... \textOmega` macros available in all font encodings.)

With LyX, just add `\usepackage{textalpha}` to Document>Settings>LaTeX preamble
and select "Unicode `[utf8]` under Document>Settings>Language>LaTeX encoding.